update-alternatives of CUDA versions not shown
Summary: I'm trying to include an additional version of CUDA in update-alternatives however it does not show up after adding it to PATH and when querying.
Information
Three versions of CUDA installed on a Linux machine as shown:
$ ls /usr/local
>>> bin  cuda  cuda-12  cuda-12.2  cuda-12.3  cuda-12.4  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src

Added cuda-12.2 to PATH in the ~/.bashrc file:
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-12.2/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-12.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

I have source compiled the bashrc file and restarted the terminal and server.
Problem
CUDA-12.2 does not show up when querying or config of update-alternatives
$sudo update-alternatives --query cuda

There are 2 choices for the alternative cuda (providing /usr/local/cuda).

  Selection    Path                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/local/cuda-12.4   124       auto mode
  1            /usr/local/cuda-12.3   123       manual mode
  2            /usr/local/cuda-12.4   124       manual mode

Question
How do I get CUDA-12.2 to show up in update-alternatives maintenace?

update-alternatives doesn't magically detect alternatives in /usr/local - you have to install them. Presumably you or whoever administers this system did that for the older versions and forgot to do it for the new version.

The partial answer was provided in the first immediate response to the post from muru (i.e. how to use "update-alternatives").
In my case, this was solved with one line of code (after learning what update-alternatives was)...
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/cuda cuda /usr/local/cuda-12.2 122

